# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail getting this error

Tags: java, testing, ssh, jsch

```
  package util;
  import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
  import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
  import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
  import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
  import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
  import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;


      public class JschTransferlinuxWindows 
   {
   
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
   String hostname = "10.10.139.79";
  String username = "root";
  String password = "*******";
  String copyTo;
  String copyFrom = "/mnt/fs0/Diff/*";
  copyTo = "C:\\Users\\akshay_gawand\\Desktop\\8.3\\Transfer";
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  Session session = null;
  System.out.println("Trying to connect.....");
   try {
 session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  session.setPassword(password);
   session.connect();
   Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
  channel.connect();
 ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
  sftpChannel.get(copyFrom, copyTo);
  sftpChannel.exit();
   session.disconnect();
  } catch (JSchException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SftpException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
     }
   System.out.println("Done !!");
     }
  }
```

I am getting below error after executing above code:

```
Trying to connect.....
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
Done !!
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:520)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:286)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
at util.JschTransferlinuxWindows.main(JschTransferlinuxWindows.java:29)
```

Comment: How does the question relates to _Selenium_?

Comment: In order to identify the root cause You need to give us the output of jsch logger.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated jsch libraries to the latest and It has been resolved.